# Checking for multiple strings in python in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```
    mot={"READ":["0001",2],"MOVER":["0010",4],"MOVEM":["0011",2],"ADD":["0101",1],"COMP":["0110",2],"BC":["0111",3],"PRINT":["1000",5],"STOP":["1001",8]}
```

It consists of an instruction followed by its code in binary and the amount of bytes it takes.

I read an input line from a file and store it in the variable str2. I want to check if any of the strings in the above dictionary occur in str2.

Now, I am using this code to check if that happens:

```
    if any(x in str2 for x in mot):
        #do something
```

Now, my problem is: I have a location variable. In place of do something I want to write:

```
    location=location+mot[x][1]
```

That is, I want to increment the location variable based on which x is found. How do I do this? If I do it in the above manner, it gives me an error saying x is not defined.

Comment: Convert to traditional loop.

Comment: That option is always open. Isn't there any other way using the above format?

Comment: Location is an integer. str is a string which I am reading from an input file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this?

```
location = location + sum(mot[x][1] for x in mot if x in str2)
```

Comment: Its working. Exactly what I wanted. I'll accept your answer as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the lengths of matching instructions:

```
print sum(v[1] for x, v in mot.items() if x in str2)
```